# How do I pattern-match filenames in a batch script

Tags: batch-file, pattern-matching

### My specific situation

I want to copy files to two different locations depending on the fourth character of the file name. Monochrome images should go to B/W folder and Colour images should go to Colour Folder. The 4th character of file name will be either C or B (for Colour or Black / white).

For example, F0#CG.eps would be a color image file, and F0#BG.eps would be a monochrome image file.

I also add usernames at the end of the filename while copying. Here's what I have so far:

```
@echo off
copy *.eps* \\Server\Directory1\BW\??????????%username%.*
copy *.eps* \\Server\Directory1\COL\??????????%username%.*
```

Comment: And what is the question?!

Comment: @Biffen I want to copy the files to both the folder as per the file name.. how can i write?

Comment: Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you only need to make a slight change to your code:

```
@echo off
copy ???B*.eps* "\\Server\Directory1\BW\??????????%username%.*"
copy ???C*.eps* "\\Server\Directory1\COL\??????????%username%.*"
```

You may want to increase the number of question marks in your target names. As currently written it will only properly support names of up to 10 characters, excluding the extension.

Also, a file named `aaaB.part2.eps` would be copied as `aaaB%username%.part2.eps`. If you want `aaaB.part2%username%.eps`, then you will need a solution more like Aacini's.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**:

- I rolled-back the [Partian Shot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3680301/parthian-shot)'s modification. The substring extraction in Batch start at zero, so `!name:~3,1!` get the *fourth* character indeed.
- I added the missing percent in `%%~Xa` extension substitution.

.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for %%a in (*.eps*) do (
   set name=%%a
   if "!name:~3,1!" equ "B" (
      copy "%%a" "\\Server\Directory1\BW\%%~Na%username%.%%~Xa"
   ) else (
      copy "%%a" "\\Server\Directory1\COL\%%~Na%username%.%%~Xa"
   )
)
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what the %%~Na and %~Xa do?

Comment: @ScottBeeson: Type: `for /?`; there are several examples explained there

Comment: Interesting, never seen that.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version of @Aacini's answer that doesn't include the "%~Xa substitution error"

```
@echo off
echo Setting Environment...
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Scanning files...
for %%a in (*.eps) do (
   set name=%%a
   echo "Copying %name%..."
   if "!name:~3,1!" equ "B" (
      copy "%%a" "\\Server\Directory1\BW\%username%"
   ) else (
      copy "%%a" "\\Server\Directory1\COL\%username%"
   )
)
pause
```

Comment: @Aacini I used the above script and it is copying all the files directly to Colour folder, irrespective of 4th character in file name whether it is B or C. I guess some error in mentioning 4th character of the file name in line("!name:~3,1!" equ "B")... what are the other possibilities that it can go wrong..?

Comment: I tested this version and it worked fine.  Keep in mind it's case sensitive.  "bbbbbbbb.eps" will go to the COL directory.

Comment: Scott, I get all the file names in upper case only, so there should not be any problem with character case sensitive. But even it is not working, I have copied the above code exactly and trying but it is not executing at all. Now I am trying to use (%1) instead of (*.eps) to just copy the selected file only not all eps extension, please let me know further... thanks

Comment: I added some "Debugging".  Run it again and tell us if you get any output.

Comment: Scott, I tried your debugged version, now it's a different result.
When I try Black&White (B) file it copies directly to first destination BW folder, no issues. But when I try to copy with Colour file it gives me error like this is 
"Copying........"
G:\Asura\COLOUR\COL_IN\????????????????????????????LOGESH.*
The system cannot find the file specified. 0 files copied. Press any continue... and it quits...
Please let me where it is wrong many thanks....